# Child Theme Change Colors - Less Mixins in Magento 2

Tags: theme, less, luma-theme

I would like to know how to change colors and follow the proper naming conventions in my _theme.less file.  I have grunt working on my local developer machine to compile the LESS files into css.

From the link below it states:

http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/docs/index.html

```
@btn__color: @color-brownie;
@btn-primary__color: @color-white;
@btn-secondary__color: @color-white;
```

I also have been successful at using:

`@page__background-color: @color-gray20;`

`@primary__color: @color-gray90;`

Where can I find a list of knowing all of the color options for the available mixings.  For example
`@page__background-color: @color-red;` does not work and `@page__background-color: @color-black;` works also `@page__background-color: @color-white;` works.

Is there a place to find all of these colors available to me by extending Luma?  Also, what is the scenario (give example?) of proper way to define my own custom color as a mixin?  Does this go in the _theme.less file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get all color variables from the `/lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_colors.less` file.

And you can add your own color variables into `/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/css/source/_variables.less` or other less files.

Comment: Can you add an example of the Proper way to create a custom color?  I have read the LESS documentation.  Is it the same here?
```@base: #f938ab;```  Magento documentation states to please follow the accepted coding conventions.

Comment: Yes, you can add your own color variables like, @header_bg_color: #f5f5f5; Then you can use this variable in your other less files, eg: .page-header { background-color: @header_bg_color; }